# Direct Collocation method for muti-body system

Tags: drake

I am very happy to learn Direct Collocation method from Underactuated Robotic course from MIT. 
One question about how to implement this method for a plant built from urdf/sdf. I explain my question using the examples of pendulum/dircol_swingup.py and acrobat/dircol_swingup.py. 
They import XXX_plant.o and xxxx_geometry.o from pydrake. I can find them under drake/example (c++ version).  In this version, they don't need urdf /sdf to build dynamic, plant and geometry.

It turn out a little difficult to follow this pattern to build a urdf/sdf base plant for a beginner. My question is: is it compatible to implement Direct Collocation method with a urdf.sdf plant?   If yes, could you provide a example?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example [here](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/c3422ad4b624290688ef9e00b87b940c91247a32/underactuated/cartpole/dircol_swingup.py) (and more coming soon... I'm working on that chapter of the notes this coming week).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I feel lucky it is simple beauty.

Comment: It works for the double pendulum.                                             
But another 2D-hopper case, an error happens, like this:                                            
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: InputPort::Eval(): required InputPort[0] (geometry_query) of System ::_ (MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>) is not connected.

Comment: MultibodyPlant's that have contact need to be wired to a SceneGraph (which handles all of the collision detection).  Although that particular error is clear and easy to resolve, you will run into more problems -- the topic of applying trajectory optimization to systems with non-smooth (or stiff) models of contact is an active topic that we will also discuss in upcoming lectures in underactuated.